# Schedule the previous successfully build in team-city

Tags: teamcity-9.0

For some build process cases. I need to schedule the previous successfully build in team-city. I need to trigger this automatically during Monday.

For Some Cost Cutting plan I will delete instance at weekend and re-build during Monday morning. I need to schedule trigger to take revision from last successful build (not from VCS commit).

Comment: If you've already built it then nothing changes - why rebuild it? You could expose this as an artifact. Can I ask why you have to take this approach? - I just want to challenge the process before providing a solution.

Comment: Hi Evolve,   Thanks for your reply..  I will delete azure cloud on Friday night for cost cutting purposes.. so i need to deploy on Monday morning..  during Monday morning deployment i need the cloud service with same code, no need to latest changes from VCS.

Comment: Currently i am doing this in manual i need to set it automated... the manual process are  
Go to the last Success build Page and Select Changes Tab, VCS Root and Change show there. I will click run icon in latest change "Run bulid with this Change"